# Could not detect default resource locations for test class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I want to implement JUnit 5 test in order to test services:

***JPA Repository:***

```
@Repository
public interface RiskFilterRepository extends JpaRepository<RiskFilters, Integer> {
    .....
}
```

***Service Interface:***

```
public interface RiskFilterService {
    ......
}
```

***Service implementation:***

```
@Service
@Qualifier("riskFilterService")
@Transactional
public class RiskFilterServiceImpl implements RiskFilterService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private RiskFilterRepository dao;
    ...
}
```

***Service for testing:***

```
@Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("riskFilterService")
    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

    public void validateBinCountryCheckFilter() throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {
        ......
    }
}
```

***JUnit test***

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @Transactional
    public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest    {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier(value = "entityManager")
        EntityManager manager;

        @Autowired
        private RiskFilterRepository repository;

        @BeforeEach
        public void beforeEachTest() throws IOException {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
        }

        @Test
        public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {
           ....
        }    
    }
```

I get this error when I run the JUnit code:

```
 Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [org.datalis.rest.api.server.filter.bincountrycheck.BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest]: BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
```

Do you know how I can implement properly this test?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to add a spring application class one package less.

```
package org.datalis.rest;// <-- This is very important. Thus, component scan will have the right configuration.
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it will start the complete application which is huge. Is there some way to mockup only the service that I need will lowest possible classes?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I think `@SpringBootTest` is an integration test, which is why it loads the entire application. Did you try to run the test without the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question under @reflexdemon 's answer, you could do something like this to mock your repository / service:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest {

    @Mock
    private RiskFilterRepository riskFilterRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEachTest() throws IOException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {

    // Instruct the mock what to return when RiskFilterRepository#findAll is called
    when(riskFilterRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(List.of());

    // Call that instructed method
    List<RiskFilters> riskFilters = riskFilterRepository.findAll();

    assertNotNull(riskFilters);
    }
}
```

Don't use `@SpringBootTest` if you don't need it, because it loads the whole Application Context. For more information see [this reference](https://pivotal.io/application-modernization-recipes/testing/spring-boot-testing-best-practices).